# Strange Short Circuit

Tags: short-circuit, spark

Can someone explain me how a **60V 5A power supply** can generate that **super hot arc** (second circuit in the video)? I made the video, and no, there's no hack here, I'm just trying to understand what's going on

**Edit**: The moment the arc is created we get 40V and 5A in the power supply, so there's a voltage drop of 10V in the resitors (V = RI <=> V =2 * 5). Considering that, the arc we see only has 30V!!! How is an arc possible with such low voltage?

https://www.reddit.com/link/s1hp7u/video/t8qu4v4ta3b81/player

Comment: Could you expand on why you think it should *not* produce the arc?

Comment: Sounds like arc welding to me - done a few hours of that, but thought the open circuit voltage was about 80V...

Comment: What is missing from your schematic is the power supply internals.  When you add the 2Ω external, then the power supply is able to handle the load without folding back so much that the arc is extinguished.

Comment: Note that this is why 250V AC switches have a ridiculously low DC rating like 12 or 30V.

Comment: Brhans, I clarified the post. user_1818839, that's an interesting point

Answer (score 3):

Placing two resistors in series keeps the voltage high while still operating the supply  at maximum current (I.e. maximum power).

Without the resistors the supply will quickly drop out of regulation and ultimately shut down due to the low resistance of the short. A good power supply will continue to deliver 5A , as this requires only a few volts: all that will be accomplished is the heating of the metal. A few volts is not enough to ionize the air continuously.  You can see this in the first half of the video where there is indeed a spark but without the sustained arc shown in the second half of the video.

High current **and** high voltage are required to maintain an arc.

Comment: Even if the regulator drops out of regulation, it can deliver 300 watts if it can do so without shutting itself down. The two resistors only drop the voltage from 60 to 50 at 5 A, so that would be 250 watts at the arc.

Comment: Exactly, if you need high voltage and high current to sustain an arc, why is the arc sustained at less than 40 Volts (some of the voltage drops in the resistors)?

Comment: The moment the arc is created we get 40V and 5A in the power supply, so there's a voltage drop of 10V in the resitors (V = RI <=> V =2 * 5). Considering that, the arc we see only as 30V, This is what's puzzling me.

Comment: 30V and the current is high enough in this case to keep the plasma hot. The plasma spark is at 40-60V.